# Spring 3 data fixtures alternatives

Tags: java, spring-mvc, fixtures

We've been using the db_unit maven plug-in to generate fixtures for our Spring 3 webapp. However, we use multiple xml files for different data for different tables and only the 1.0-SNAPSHOT version of db_unit maven plug-in supports this. It seems like the maven db_unit is not active anymore. Are there any alternative ways to create fixtures for a Spring 3 project? (via maven or Controller startups etc.)